# Mvvmcross request runtime permissions MvxFragmentActivity

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using

> MvxFragmentActivity
>   in my application , it is kinda old application (created at 2015), now I need to update it . So I need to request runtime permission for location , but unfortunately , I'm nor able to do this. Is seems that MvxFragmentActivity doesn't support it, or I don't know what is the problem.. here are packages I use :

```
    <packages>
  <package id="MvvmCross" version="6.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Droid.Fragging" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Color" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.DownloadCache" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Network" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Location" version="6.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.PortableSupport" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Plugin.Permissions" version="3.0.0.12" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="Softlion.XamSvg.Free" version="1.2.1.4" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="SplunkMint.Xamarin.Android" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="sqlite-net-pcl" version="1.5.231" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="SQLitePCL.raw_basic" version="0.8.6" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="22.2.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="22.2.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="22.2.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="22.2.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Facebook.Android" version="4.6.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices" version="22.0.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="ZXing.Net.Mobile" version="1.4.7.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
</packages>
```

Comment: does it work now ?

Comment: I haven't completed updating packages

Answer (score 0):

**RunTime Permissions** is the new feature in **Android 6.0 (API level 23)**

so you could try this:

right click your project -> **Properties** -> **Application** -> **Compile using Android version (Target Framework)** - > select **Android 6.0** or later

if not useful ,you could think about copy your project into a new solution with latest version

Comment: it is impossible to copy my project, where are a lot of data in there. Also updating target version is not solution, I need to implement runtime permission because android target version is more than 6.0 now .

Comment: So what's wrong with you now ？Unable to call request permission API ?Could you post some specific error messages ?